# What does (void)variableName mean

Tags: c++, variables

I saw following code few times

```
void func(SomeTypeEGInt varname) {
    (void)varname;
}
```

I wish to know what it means and why people implement such functions.

Answer (score 2):

It tell the compiler that those variables are **unused**. It is used to **prevent the warnings** which you will get.

Comment: additional, you cold achieve the same effect (suppress warning) by `void func( SomeTypeEGInt ) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

The `(void)varname;` pattern is typically used to silence compiler warning about unused arguments. So this example is actually an empty function which does nothing.